# The compatibility while using both writing-mode & text-overflow in Safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari

This seems to be a bug, when I'm using both `writing-mode: vertical-rl` and `text-overflow: ellipsis` in safari, the ellipsis is not fitting the writing-mode. the style of the ellipsis is like `unset`.

This link is my demo, please view it in safari. This demo is running in the chorme, firefox, opera well.

https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/519981/

how can I fix this problem

Answer (score 0):

I fix this problem by using the `transform: rotate(90deg)` 
This is my code
[Code Link](https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/522786/)